# Running a python script once after app server starts - Django, Docker-Compose

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

**Desired outcome:**

After I run `docker-compose up` I want the server to start (docker-compose runs the database and web services) and then after the server is up and working run a python script that contains a web scraping code which puts the scraped contents into the DB (and only run it once). The code is using Django models to store the data in DB.

**Problem:**

After running `docker-compose up` the database and server are run correctly, I can access the website on localhost and get the API responses,
but it seems the scraping script is never executed. I have found a way to run the code using `ready` function built into Django before, but it does not work as intended (it stops the server from running until the whole scraping completes which is not optimal as I want the scraping to run in the background). When I tried using a separate service to run the script, even using `depends_on` did not work, the service was still being run as soon as web did and then fail due to "File not found". What would be the right way to go about doing this?

**Code:**

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.6'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:10.1-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
  web:
    build: .
    image: teonite_scraper
    command: bash -c "python /teonite_webscraper/teonite_webscraper/manage.py migrate && python /teonite_webscraper/teonite_webscraper/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080 && python /teonite_webscraper/teonite_webscraper/scraper/scrape.py"
    volumes:
      - .:/teonite_webscraper
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      - SECRET_KEY=changemeinprod
    depends_on:
      - db

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

`scrape.py` (scraping script):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from teonite_webscraper.scraper.helpers import get_links
from teonite_webscraper.scraper.models import Article, Author
import json
import re
print('Starting...')
# For implementation check helpers.py, grabs all the article links from blog
links = get_links('https://teonite.com/blog/')
# List of objects to batch inject into DB to save I/Os
objects_to_inject = []

links_in_db = list(Article.objects.all().values_list('article_link', flat=True))
authors_in_db = list(Author.objects.all().values_list('author_stub', flat=True))

for link in links:

    if not link in links_in_db:
        # Grab article page
        blog_post = requests.get(link)
        # Prepare soup
        soup = BeautifulSoup(blog_post.content, 'lxml')
        # Gets the json with author data from page meta
        json_element = json.loads(soup.find_all('script')[1].get_text())

        # All of the below can be done within Articles() as parameters, but for clarity
        # I prefer separate lines, and DB models cannot be accessed outside
        # ready() at this stage anyway so refactoring to separate function wouldn't be possible
        post_data = Article()
        post_data.article_link = link
        post_data.article_content = soup.find('section', class_='post-content').get_text()

        # Regex only grabs the last part of author's URL that contains the "nickname"
        author_stub = re.search(r'\/(\w+\-?_?\.?\w+)\/$', json_element['author']['url']).group(1)

        # Check if author is already in DB if so assign the key.
        if author_stub in authors_in_db:
            post_data.article_author = Author.objects.get(author_stub=author_stub)
        else:
            # If not, create new DB Authors item and then assign.
            new_author = Author(author_fullname=json_element['author']['name'],
                                 author_stub=author_stub)
            new_author.save()
            # Unlike links which are unique, author might appear many times and we only grab
            # them from DB once at the beginning, so adding it here to the checklist to avoid trying to
            # add same author multiple times
            authors_in_db.append(author_stub)
            post_data.article_author = new_author

        post_data.article_title = json_element['headline']
        # Append object to the list and continue
        objects_to_inject.append(post_data)

Article.objects.bulk_create(objects_to_inject)
print('Done collecting data!')
```

Comment: Does your log have any trace of the script?

Comment: Absolutely nothing. It is like it's not even being tried to run. (I even put that print at the beginning specifically to immediately see if it was run)

Comment: It's not getting run, your shell command in the `docker-compose.yml` only runs it if the Web server process exits successfully.

Comment: I see. That actually makes a lot of sense now I think about it, the question is, how should I go about running it then (to do it the right way)?

Comment: try `migrate && runserver; python scrape.py` note, there is semicolon @BartekGańcza

Comment: That does not work unfortunately.

Comment: i was able to reproduce it by myself.
try `python migrate && python scrape.py & python runserver` Here I changed order and script is ran in background. Single `&` is important. @BartekGańcza

Comment: When I do it this way, it does run the script but it gives me an import error of "ModuleNotFound" in line 3 so where I try to import from `helpers`.

Comment: @BartekGańcza this is another kind of problem :) it's needed to know where scrape.py is located and what is the directory structure

Comment: Yeah, I mean the imports are set up properly, the problem is I think before the server (app) is fully initialised, the scripts won't know what these modules mean and won't be able to access the database or helper functions. Unless I don't understand something here and it should be set differently for this specific case, but then I have no idea how :D